# Appending richtext to JTextPane using StyledDocument.insertString doesn't preserve fonts

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I don't know if what I'm trying to do is possible or not.

I have console where I want to append formatted text declared like this:

```
private final JTextPane statusText = new JTextPane();
```

I got a reference to its styled document like this:

```
private StyledDocument statusDocument = statusText.getStyledDocument();
```

I defined a few attributes :

```
private final SimpleAttributeSet gray;
private final SimpleAttributeSet black;
private final SimpleAttributeSet red;
```

and a helper method:

```
private void appendStatusText(String text, SimpleAttributeSet attribute) {
        final String finalText = text;
        final SimpleAttributeSet finalAttribute = attribute;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    statusDocument.insertString(statusDocument.getLength(), finalText, finalAttribute);
                } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                    log.error("Cannot add " + finalText, e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to use *appendStatusText* with one of the attributes (gray, red, black) and some text, but all it's showing is in gray, I'm expecting multicolors.

Can you help please.

PS: I got the code from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059198/jtextpane-appending-a-new-string)

Comment: maybe is/are there another issue(s), please edit you post with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @mKorbel Ok, I'll try to prepare a SSCCE, but first, can you please confirm that it's ok to mix and match different SimpleAttributeSet instances with parts of the text added to a JTextPane?

Comment: no I think that there isn't issue, another question isn't something, somehow un_clear from (@camickr's) describtion), you can [(pretty to) use one of those two codes for your SSCCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650992/how-to-change-text-color-in-the-jtextarea/9651404#9651404)

Comment: looks like the error is somewhere else, I used the SSCCE you suggested, and modified it, and now it behaves as i expect. I'll keep investigating, thanks

Comment: the problem was that the text panel had setEnabled to false, which had the effect of everything appearing gray...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `initDocument()` method of [`TextComponentDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TextComponentDemo) shows one approach to constructing such a document. The [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextComponentDemoProject/src/components/TextComponentDemo.java) appears among the [*Examples That Use Text Panes and Editor Panes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html#eg) in the tutorial article [*How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your SimpleAttributeSet and then add the attributes you want, like so:

```
private SimpleAttributeSet red = new SimpleAttributeSet();      
red.addAttribute(StyleConstants.CharacterConstants.Foreground, Color.red);
```