# How to append a string in java swing JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, styleddocument

I am creating a chat application. In this chat application, I have to use Java Swing's `JTextPane` to give style to some specific strings like the user's display name and the message's time. That's why I chose `JTextPane` over `JTextArea`. In JTextPane, I can't append the String, so I create a String buffer to append the String, then I do `jTextPane.setText(stringBuffer.toString())`.

Here is my problem: When I append a string into the `JTextPane` via a `StringBuffer`, there is a delay. How can I append a string line-by-line in a `JTextPane`?

Comment: Get the `Document` object of the `JTextPane` and use the `insertString()` method

Comment: Please have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650992/how-to-change-text-color-in-the-jtextarea/9652143#9652143)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JTextPane appending a new string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059198/jtextpane-appending-a-new-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found another similar question whose answer made use of the `StyledDocument` and calls `insertString()` method on the instance of `StyledDocument` to append text to it and then write the `StyledDocument` back to `JTextPane`: [JTextPane appending a new string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059198/jtextpane-appending-a-new-string)