# First attempt at a simple GUI

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I am attempting to teach myself how to make a GUI using Java swing and Window Builder Pro, after watching several youtube videos, and reading some tutorials I have accomplished the following.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class JetstreamFrame extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JTabbedPane tabPane;

JPanel buttonOnePanel;
JPanel buttonTwoPanel;
JPanel textDisplayPanel;
JTextPane textPane;
SpringLayout sl_textDisplayPanel;
SpringLayout springLayout;
SpringLayout sl_buttonTwoPanel;
SpringLayout sl_buttonOnePanel;
JButton ButtonTwo;
JButton ButtonOne;

public JetstreamFrame() {
    springLayout = new SpringLayout();
    getContentPane().setLayout(springLayout);

    tabPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    setupTabPane();

    buttonOnePanel = new JPanel();
    sl_buttonOnePanel = new SpringLayout();
    setupButtonOnePanel();

    ButtonOne = new JButton("Click Here!");
    setupButtonOne();

    buttonTwoPanel = new JPanel();
    sl_buttonTwoPanel = new SpringLayout();
    setupButtonTwoPanel();

    ButtonTwo = new JButton("Click Here!");
    setupButtonTwo();

    textDisplayPanel = new JPanel();
    sl_textDisplayPanel = new SpringLayout();
    setupTextDisplayPanel();

    textPane = new JTextPane();
    setupTextPane();

}

private void setupTabPane()
{
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, tabPane, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, tabPane, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, tabPane, -198, SpringLayout.SOUTH, getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, tabPane, 484, SpringLayout.WEST, getContentPane());
    getContentPane().add(tabPane);
}

private void setupButtonOnePanel()
{
    tabPane.addTab("Tab One", null, buttonOnePanel, null);
    buttonOnePanel.setLayout(sl_buttonOnePanel);
}

private void setupButtonOne()
{
    ButtonOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {

        }
    });
    sl_buttonOnePanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, ButtonOne, 99, SpringLayout.NORTH, buttonOnePanel);
    sl_buttonOnePanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, ButtonOne, 187, SpringLayout.WEST, buttonOnePanel);
    buttonOnePanel.add(ButtonOne);
}

private void setupButtonTwoPanel()
{
    tabPane.addTab("Tab Two", null, buttonTwoPanel, null);
    buttonTwoPanel.setLayout(sl_buttonTwoPanel);
}

private void setupButtonTwo()
{
    ButtonTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {

        }
    });
    sl_buttonTwoPanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, ButtonTwo, 99, SpringLayout.NORTH, buttonTwoPanel);
    sl_buttonTwoPanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, ButtonTwo, 187, SpringLayout.WEST, buttonTwoPanel);
    buttonTwoPanel.add(ButtonTwo);
}

private void setupTextDisplayPanel()
{
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, textDisplayPanel, 6, SpringLayout.SOUTH, tabPane);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, textDisplayPanel, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, textDisplayPanel, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, textDisplayPanel, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, getContentPane());
    getContentPane().add(textDisplayPanel); 
    textDisplayPanel.setLayout(sl_textDisplayPanel);
}

private void setupTextPane()
{
    sl_textDisplayPanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, textPane, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, textDisplayPanel);
    sl_textDisplayPanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, textPane, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, textDisplayPanel);
    sl_textDisplayPanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, textPane, 182, SpringLayout.NORTH, textDisplayPanel);
    sl_textDisplayPanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, textPane, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, textDisplayPanel);
    textDisplayPanel.add(textPane);
}

public void start()
{
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

The premise of this code is to create a window with multiple tabs, and a text area at the bottom that is visible no matter which tab the user is in. I have created the text area, the tabs, the buttons, as well as the button event listeners for this GUI.

Unfortunately, none of the tutorials I have read have showed me how to print anything into the text area. I would like to have something along the lines of

```
System.out.println();
```

attached to each of the buttons, and have that printing show up in the text area, but I do not know how to accomplish this.

I would also like to know if the text area I have created with result in a scroll bar along the side should the printed text extend beyond the visible frame.

Comment: *"using Java swing and Window Builder Pro, after watching several youtube videos,.."*  (shudder)  Long road ahead.  Bookmark this link - [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).  Many of your upcoming questions will end up with links back to sections of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
textpane.append("TEXTHERE");
```

Will add any needed text to your text area based on an `event`. When we `append()` text we can also add new text onto an existing passage. If you want to clear the `JTextArea` then I recommend you call the `setText()` method.

A `JScrollPane` is needed to add a scroll bar to a `JTextArea` which can be done by the following:

```
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(TEXTAREAHERE);
```

Personally I like to set my scroll pane's properties to this, to ensure that the JScrollBar only is able to scroll Up and Down and remove the Left and Right scrolling:

`scrollPane.setHorizonalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you could simply use the `append()` method.

Here is more about [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html)

To test it out, add a call to it in one of your button events (they don't seem to be doing anything at the moment). So you could do, `jTextArea.append("Did it print?");` and click that button to see it work.

**Edit**
It looks like you are using JTextPane, in that case, maybe use `setText()`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059198/jtextpane-appending-a-new-string)