# JTextPane append HTML string

Tags: java, html, formatting, append, jtextpane

I can parse the content of a JTextPane witout any problems in HTML:

```
textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setContentType("text/html");
textPane.setText(<b>Hello!</b>);
// ...
setVisible(true);
```

this results in

**Hello!**

But whenever I try to append a String to textPane, using

```
styledDoc = (StyledDocument) textPane.getStyledDocument();
styledDoc.insertString(styledDoc .getLength(), <b>Goodbye!</b>, null );
```

(as seen [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059198/jtextpane-appending-a-new-string)), my output is

> **Hello!** `<b>Goodbye!</b>`

(without whitespaces) - so the html formatting is skipped.

How can I append a String to my JTextPane Object and keep the HTML formation for the added part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use e.g.

```
HTMLDocument doc=(HTMLDocument) textPane.getStyledDocument();
doc.insertAfterEnd(doc.getCharacterElement(doc.getLength()),"<b>Goodbye!</b>");
```

Or

```
HTMLEditorKit kit=(HTMLEditorKit )textPane.getEditorKit();
```

and use the method if you would like to insert paragraph/table or another branch element

```
public void insertHTML(HTMLDocument doc, int offset, String html,
                       int popDepth, int pushDepth,
                       HTML.Tag insertTag)
```

Comment: The first suggestion doesn't work: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument cannot be cast to javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument

Comment: @Dominik obviously your textPane has not HTMLEditorKit. Try to call `textPane.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit())` before.